# Cannot Add Tenancy to Weviate Class

Tags: weaviate

I have a local instance of weaviate running on my machine.  I am trying to enable multi-tenancy [by following this guidance](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/manage-data/multi-tenancy) and by utilizing this code:

```
client.schema.create_class({
    'class': 'MultiTenancyClass',
    'multiTenancyConfig': {'enabled': True}
})

client.schema.add_class_tenants(
  class_name='MultiTenancyClass',  # The class to which the tenants will be added
  tenants=[Tenant(name='tenantA'), Tenant(name='tenantB')]
)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> weaviate.exceptions.UnexpectedStatusCodeException: Add classes
> tenants! Unexpected status code: 404, with response body: {'code':
> 404, 'message': 'path /v1/schema/MultiTenancyClass/tenants was not
> found'}.

Is it not possible to add multi-tenancy to a local instance of weaviate?

Comment: when I try to update my class to use mutli-tenancy via ```response = client.schema.update_config(CLASS_NAME, {"multiTenancyConfig": {"enabled": True}})``` I get a warning message
```compaction halted due to shard READONLY status```
However, when I check the status of my shard via ```shards_response = client.schema.get_class_shards(CLASS_NAME)``` it shows that my shard is ready ```[{'name': 'TmSEG9ZtZpl8', 'status': 'READY'}]```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what went wrong for you. But I can assure you that multitenancy **does** work on a local instance of weaviate.

The same issue with solutions has been discussed [here](https://forum.weaviate.io/t/cannot-add-tenancy-to-weaviate-class/496/6).

I just want to tell future readers to use the client v4 instead of v3 from now on, since v3 has been marked as deprecated.